# Create actionscript Application file for Flex project

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I'm trying to create Flex project with an `actionscript` application file, not a `mxml` file.

I simply use this code :

```
package
{   

import spark.components.Application;

    public class Test extends Application
    {       
        public function Test(){
            super();    
        }       
    }
}
```

But I receive this error :

```
TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/initialize()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:261]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::initialize()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2097]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/initHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2582]
```

How can I create a full AS application class for Flex project please ?

Comment: In a Flex Project; you're main application file has to be MXML.  Everything else can be ActionScript, though.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Hi, in my project I use mxml files only for skin classes. I simply wanted to follow my "convention". So, I will use MXML file for my main application. Thanks

Comment: please copy the comment as answer. I don't want to steal points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Flex Project; you're main application file has to be MXML. Everything else can be ActionScript, though.