# Not able to use addElement in the flash-builder class

Tags: flash-builder

I am trying to experiment with graphics api in flash builder.

1) The default application is "Main.as" ( not Main.mxml)
2) The application uses Spark  (Not the mx package)

What i am looking at is using the function addElement to show the shape in the following code

Here is the code :

```
package app
{
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Sprite;

import spark.core.SpriteVisualElement;

public class Main    
{
    public function Main()
    {
        var shape:Shape =new Shape() ;
        shape.graphics.lineStyle(3,0xff);
        shape.graphics.moveTo(0,0);
        shape.graphics.lineTo(300,300);

        var sve:SpriteVisualElement = new SpriteVisualElement() ;
        sve.addChild(shape);

                   //***********************************
        addElement( sve) ;// <<< Compiler error here
                   //***********************************

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class must extend a class that supports visual elements.

In this case, you are attempting to extend Spark [`Application`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Application.html) class:

```
package
{
    import spark.components.Application;

    public class Main extends Application
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks. But now i get the error as mentioned here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972818/create-actionscript-application-file-for-flex-project   . The solution is ticked.. but i don't wanna use the "mxml" as the default application. I need to use ".as" file as default application.

Comment: Flex main application file must be MXML.  Are you using features of Flex?  If not, create a pure ActionScript project and link libraries as needed.

Comment: What are the features of flex ? I am not planning to use and component from flex. I only want to use "spark" package, for basic drawing api . Tht's all.

Comment: Spark is not required of drawing API as you have implemented above using [`Graphics`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html).  Use a `Sprite` or `Shape` instead `SpriteVisualElement`.